# match elements by data attribute and id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to compare elements using jQuery. Basically for every element with a certain data attribute, I want to "appendChild" another element that has a matching ID.

So in the following example, 'a' has a data attribute of data-dropdown="drop-delivery-options". The second element has an ID="drop-delivery-options", so they match. I can select elements with this ID but how do I select elements that match data-attributes/IDs?

So a function that would be like:

```
If elementA[data-attribute] = elementB[ID] { 
    (elementA).appendChild(elementB) 
}
```

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop-delivery-options" class="button">Add Option</a>

<div id="drop-delivery-options" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content table-options drop-delivery-options">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Add Deposit Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Cash Pickup</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Send to Card</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Home Delivery</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data-dropdown` attribute to select the `select` element, then use `appendTo()` to append it to the `a`. Note though that given your example you will end up with nested `a` elements, which is invalid. You should look to change the parent `a` element to something else.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('dropdown')).appendTo(this);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mqtx8d59/)

Comment: I guess I should clarify, I am trying to make the second element a child element of the first one. so `<a><div></div></a>`

Comment: That's what this code is doing. My bad with the note about the `select`. For some reason I thought there was one in your HTML

Comment: I have upvoted, thank you. I guess the upvote doesn't show up until I have 15 points. I'm working on it!